# What happens if `compare_exchange_weak` is called on a dangling pointer? How is the code in my textbook safe?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, stdatomic, compare-and-swap

I feel like there could about the a dangling pointer in this example implementation of a lock-free stack in *C++: Concurrency in Action*. The author, Anthony Williams, provides a beginning for the lock-free stack class as:

```cpp
class LockFreeStack {
  private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;

        Node(T const& data_) : data(data_) {}
    };
    std::atomic<Node*> head;
  public:
    void push(T const& data) {
        Node* const new_node = new Node(data);
        new_node->next = head.load();
        while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
    }
};
```

Williams then discusses how to implement `pop`. He says, "push() doesn’t touch the node once it’s been added to the stack, so the thread that called pop() must be the only thread that can touch the node, and it can safely delete it." Nodes to delete are initially added on to a `std::atomic<Node*> pending_deletion_head`, and a variable `std::atomic<unsigned> threads_in_pop` stores the count of threads that are accessing `pop`. The entire chain extending from `pending_deletion_head` is finally deleted when `threads_in_pop` is zero.

This makes sense to me in general, but I'm confused about how `push` is safe. Specifically, couldn't `new_node->next` in the line `while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));` be a dangling pointer with the given implementation of `pop`?

Comment: Dangling pointers are only unsafe if they are _dereferenced_.  These pointers can be safely examined and copied.

Comment: `new_node->next` is only accessed before a successful compare-exchange. At that point `new_node` has not been "published", so to speak. The local thread is the only one knowing `new_node`

Comment: @DrewDormann You're totally right, sorry for the silly mistake!

Comment: @DrewDormann Examining/copying an invalid pointer is implementation defined (<https://wg21.link/CWG1438>). It's allowable for `dangling_pointer != nullptr` or `void* p = dangling_pointer;` to segfault. I've been told this is the case on some microarchitectures

Comment: @Artyer That's horrifying.  Thank you for the education, nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `push` is safe because you only access `new_node->next`. `new_node` is always locally created with `new Node`, so it cannot be a dangling pointer. The statement:

```cpp
while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node)) {}
```

... is effectively doing:

```cpp
while(true) {
    // syntax from transactional memory TS
    atomic_noexcept {
        // using -> is safe here because up to this point,
        // new_node is always a not-null pointer
        if (head == new_node->next) {
            // new_node->next may be dangling after this, but we don't care
            // and return from the function
            head = new_node;
            break;
        }
        else {
            new_node->next = head;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Accessing `new_node->next` is always safe because `new_node` is the new node you've created earlier.
`new_node->next` might be replaced with `head` during the loop, which makes it an invalid pointer, but `new_node` itself is never dangling, which makes this okay.